# remove special characters in python 3.7

Tags: python, regex

I've been testing for rip the url using python and I get the result from str

itdUrlforrip.text content:
http://itdmusic.in/category/new-releases/page/4

the complete code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import re
import regex
from pyquery import PyQuery

#get each
link1 = open('/Users/R/Downloads/itdUrlforrip.txt','r').read()
list1 = link1.split('\n')
list2 = []
for eachlink1 in list1:
    linkSub1 = requests.get(eachlink1).text
    splitContent = linkSub1.split("Facebook")
    splitContent1 = splitContent[0]
    list2.append(splitContent1)

list2GLStr = ("\n".join(list2))
urlAll = regex.findall('itdmusic\.in\/\d\d\/.+\.html', list2GLStr)
allUrlrmDup1 = list(dict.fromkeys(urlAll))

#get list of url from input
allUrlrmDup1Ah = regex.sub('itdmusic', 'http://itdmusic', str(allUrlrmDup1))
allUrlrmDup1Ah2 = regex.sub('\'', '', str(allUrlrmDup1Ah))
allUrlrmDup1Ah3 = regex.sub('\[', '', str(allUrlrmDup1Ah2))
allUrlrmDup1Ah4 = regex.sub('\]', '', str(allUrlrmDup1Ah3))
allUrlrmDup1AhGL = ("\n".join(list(allUrlrmDup1Ah4.split(', '))))
allUrlrmDup1AhList = allUrlrmDup1AhGL.split('\n')

list3 = []
list4 = []
for eachlink2 in allUrlrmDup1AhList:
    linkSub2 = requests.get(eachlink2).text
    urlGdr = regex.findall('drive\.google\.com\/.{41}', linkSub2)
    urlOth = regex.findall('https\:\/\/www\d\d\d\.zippyshare\.com\/v.{19}|https\:\/\/www\d\d\.zippyshare\.com\/v.{19}|https\:\/\/www\d\.zippyshare\.com\/v.{19}|https?:\/\/douploads\.com\/.{12}|https?:\/\/www\.mirrored\.to\/.{14}|https?:\/\/mir\.cr\/.{8}|https?:\/\/hexupload\.net\/.{12}|https?:\/\/intoupload\.net\/.{12}|https?:\/\/www\.dropbox\.com\/s\/.{15}|https?:\/\/dbree\.org\/v\/.{6}|https?:\/\/dropapk\.to\/.{12}|https?:\/\/www\.sendspace\.com\/file\/.{6}|https?:\/\/gestyy\.com\/.{6}|https?:\/\/ouo\.io\/\w{6}|https?:\/\/mega\.nz.{55}|https?:\/\/bit\.ly.{8}', linkSub2)
    urlska = regex.findall('https?\:\/\/itdmusic\.in\/skipads\/.+\/\'', linkSub2)
    urlskaStr = str(urlska)
    urlska2 = regex.sub('\/\'', '', urlskaStr)
    list3.append(urlGdr)
    list3.append(urlOth)
    list4.append(urlska2)
```

then I

```
print(list4)
```

and the result is

```
'[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '["http://itdmusic.in/skipads/2020/03/12/luke-bryan-one-margarita-pre-single"]', '["http://itdmusic.in/skipads/2020/03/12/kota-banks-italiana-single"]'
```

for 32s

so is there a way to get rid of '[]' and just get the url in here?
I try bunch of things and still cannot figure out using regex and re.
I'm little bit confusing by using for xxx in xxx.

Comment: No need regex, just `[s[1:-1] for s in str_list]`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you be more detailed and also tell us what have your tried till now. Posting your code along with the question helps others to help you better

Answer (score 0):

The thing is regex.findall() returns a list and you are appending it to another list, thus you are getting the '[]'.

You should use "list4.extend(urlska2)" instead of "list4.append(urlska2)"

which would give you what you want.